# Why is my app not compatible with some devices but will load from a private server?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the play store which will install on most devices apart from an old Motorola XT320. When I search for the app on the Play Store I cannot see it.

I understand i can find out why from the developers console.I have tried loading the app from our private server and it loads fine.

One customer says the Motorola says it is not compatible with the app, but how can this be when i can load it on via private server?

Thanks

[Edit1]
My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.carefreegroup.rr3"
    android:versionCode="33"
    android:versionName="3.1"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly" 
     >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" /> -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="false" />

        <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <!-- Donut-specific flags which allow us to run on any dpi screens. -->
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name=".NfcScannerApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:debuggable = "false" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NfcscannerActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.QRCODE_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EntryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoadTransactionsMap" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewTransactions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginValidate"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewTransactionsTest"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

        <activity
            android:name=".NfcBaseActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



        <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".ZxScanner"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Allow web apps to launch Barcode Scanner by linking to http://zxing.appspot.com/scan. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="zxing.appspot.com"
                    android:path="/scan"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- We also support a Google Product Search URL. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.google.com"
                    android:path="/m/products/scan"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- And the UK version. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.google.co.uk"
                    android:path="/m/products/scan"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Support zxing://scan/?... like iPhone app -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="scan"
                    android:path="/"
                    android:scheme="zxing" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PreferencesActivity"
            android:label="@string/preferences_name"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EncodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/share_name"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- This allows us to handle sharing any plain text . -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchBookContentsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/sbc_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SEARCH_BOOK_CONTENTS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShareActivity"
            android:label="@string/share_name"
            android:screenOrientation="user"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SHARE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HistoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/history_title"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BookmarkPickerActivity"
            android:label="@string/bookmark_picker_name"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".share.AppPickerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_picker_name"
            android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HelpActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="user" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewQrCodes"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ValidateUser"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReportSomething"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GetClientDirections"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewPhoneNumbers"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GetRota"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GetRotaDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowMoreDetails"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ReplyToMessageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ViewMessagesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".SendStandaloneMessageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RecordActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MessageRecipientActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TrafficMonitorActivity"
            >
        </activity>


       <activity
            android:name=".CachedRotaActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".EmailLog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".CarePlanActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".FtpUpload"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>



       <service android:name=".SendOutstandingTransactionsIntentService" />
        <service android:name=".QueryService" />
        <service android:name=".LocationService" />
        <service android:name=".TrackingService" />

        <service android:name=".SignalService" />
        <service
            android:name=".SendOutstandingTransactions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.startatboot.MyService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


        <receiver
            android:name="AlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name="TrackingAlarmReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>




        <service
            android:name=".DeleteDuplicateTXTableService"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.startatboot.DupTXService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="DuplicateTXReceiver"
            android:process=":remote" >
        </receiver>



         <service android:name=".EmailLog" />

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />

        <service android:name=".GetHttpResponseIntentService" />
        <service android:name=".ExecutePushCommandIntentService" />
        <service android:name=".FtpUploadIntentService" />


        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                  <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3" />
                  </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".PowerKeyBroadCastReciever">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Compatibility is determined by what you defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. These criteria in turn allow Google Play to determine what devices are supported. Maybe the Motorola XT320 does not have a feature you've specified in your manifest file so it was excluded from the list of supportable devices.

Comment: @ChuongPham is there not a way in the developers console to check why a phone is not compatible? I think i have read this somewhere. do you know where in the console this feature is? i've had a look but can't find it. thanks

Comment: No, that information is held internally within Google servers. You could try contacting the Motorola or search for the device online to see what specification features it has. Other than that, contact Google to see how they determine what is compatible and what's not - they will have a list somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Android API may not be compatible. For example, the minSdkVersion of the application is greater than the version of the device.

Comment: the min is 8 and the target is 11. the device is running 2.3.6